How to convert Y-axis to HR on smooth scaled schoenfeld residual plot?
I have tried to visualise the proportional hazard (ph) assumption for my cox-ph model by plotting the smooth scaled schoenfeld residual plot. I'm working in R.
The residual plot is computed in R like this
test_ph <- cox.zph(my_cox_model, transform="identity")
plot(test_ph, resid=FALSE)

The output I get from the above code, is the y-axis representing the Beta(t) for the covariate over time (on the x-axis).
However, I'm interested in having the y-axis showing the HR. I have tried to exp() the y values like in the following codes, and then plotting, but it did not work
hr <- exp(test_ph$y)
time <- test_ph$time #X-axis is names time in the test_ph 
plot(time, hr)

How can I convert the values on the y-axis to HR for the residual plot? Is it even possible to do that, or should I code a plot for plotting the HR over time instead converting the y-axis on the residual plot? If so, I still need help to code the latter in R as well.
Thank you in advance!

My vote to close was to migrate to stats.stackexchange.com bc I think there is a statistical confusion about what Schoenfeld residuals represent.

What exactly do you think I'm confused about @IRTFM ? I do now that the residual plot is showing the estimate of the regression coefficient for the covariate over time. I have used it to visualise if the covariate is violating the ph assumption. Now I'm asking if it is possible to convert the y axis by exp(), to see the HR over time.  Is it because I'm mixing two different things together? I thought that if I exp() the y axis, would give me the HR over time on the plot. Could you elaborate more?

What I’m reading about Schoenfeld residuals is telling me that they are actually estimates of the difference between the measured covariate and an estimate of the covariate. So if what I’ve now read in two different places is correct you are asking for an impossible result. That’s not what I read in ?zph so I’m also hesitant to attempt an answer without seeing what a real statistician would reply.

Read this comment from EdM https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/547137/382622  EdM. Quoting from the comment "The smoothed plot is thus an estimate of the time dependence of the coefficient for the covariate". @IRTFM What I understand from EdM answer, is that if I exp() the values from the y-axis on a residual plot, then I get the anti-log HR.

Right. That was was I understood from the zph help page, but it didn’t agree with the other stuff I read. Don’t forget that there will be no estimates for censored cases. And next time you post, do NOT say “it didn’t work”. Instead say what did happpen and contrast it with what you expected.

@DeviSita You can use plot(test_ph, resid=FALSE, hr = TRUE)

@IRTFM I think the question is relevant and belongs to SO. Prof. Terry Therneau (author of {survival}) even provided a direct way to achieve OP desired result, see my comment above to @DeviSita.

@Thomas It doesn't have a [MCVE} and the qestion remains vague even though the OP accepted the answer but then posted a reply saying the result "didn't look good" so it remain unclear what "good" means. I think that if the uncertainty in the OP's mind became clarified and a clear message about what he considers an acceptable result became clear on a particular set of data that it probably would be a suitable SO Q. If you nderstand what the OP is looking for you could attempt an edit of the question with a dataset you thought illustrated the problem and the s=desired otcome.

@IRTFM: Devi Sita posted the question on Cross Validated as you suggested. The question was open and unanswered so I posted the answer there. Maybe the question on Cross Validated should be linked here in the close notice?

@Thomas  Don’t think you can edit can edit close notices. Your comment will be the best link that can be done. Your CV answer has the virtue of having a reproducible example. If this question ever got to that quality level it could have gotten reopened.

Does your model have multiple predictors? Are you getting this error?
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ

If so, the problem is that test_ph$y has multiple columns, one for each predictor, and plot can only do one at a time. Try:
hr <- exp(test_ph$y)
time <- test_ph$time #X-axis is names time in the test_ph 
plot(time, hr[,1])

To see the plot for the first predictor.

thanks for answering @Eonema . It was the problem. and it fixed it! Thanks! But my plot of HR over time does not look good as the residual plot itself. Do you have any suggestions on how to plot the HR over time?
